# passing parameters to ssrs through querystring

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, query-string

I have to pass 4 parameters to ssrs report, this is how my url looks

```
Response.Redirect("http://ups117850/rpt/Pages/Rept.aspx?ItemPath=%2feMaaS%2feMaaS&rs:Command=render&studentId=" + studentID + "&startdate=" + StartDate + "&enddate=" + EndDate + "&type=" + type);
```

studentid=1031

startdate=4/1/2011

enddate=4/30/2011

type=student

ssrs throws error 'parameters validation failed"

Comment: Could you post the values you're trying to pass on querystring? (studentID, StartDate, etc)

Comment: See if you can grab and share an actual sample of the URL that gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is in the StartDate and EndDate that you are passing. If these are actual DateTime values you may need to format the resulting string properly. Does the code below work any differently?

```
Response.Redirect("http://ups117850/rpt/Pages/Rept.aspx?ItemPath=%2feMaaS%2feMaaS&rs:Command=render&studentId=" + studentID + "&startdate=" + StartDate.ToString("s") + "&enddate=" + EndDate.ToString("s") + "&type=" + type);
```